# Apply for Korean Visa in Japan as an exchange student

Tags: visas, japan, south-korea, vietnamese-citizens

I am curently a Vietnamese exchange student in Japan.  And I just got here in March 20th. My Japan Visa is 6 months.

I am intending to travel to South Korea in September. I want to apply for the visa beforehand in August or July. Until then I will have only stayed in Japan for 4 or 5 months.

Will it affect anything? I am scared that I stay in Japan for such a too short term to apply for Korea Visa.

And I know before that I will have to apply for Japan visa extension

Answer (score 1):

[Embassy of Republic of Korea in Japan](http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/jp-ko/wpge/m_1153/contents.do): {Written in Korean, translated by me}

> ## General Sightseeing (C-3-9)
>
> Visa details:
>
> Trips less than 90 days, visa valid for 3 months
>
> Required form:
>
> Application form, passport, photo, fee, proof of financial support during your stay in Korea or ID (Residence card)
>
> - If you are student from Southeastern Asia region, you need a proof of enrollment from your school AND proof of financial support (if you don't have any, you need it from your parents in your home country)
> - Depending on your educational institution, more or less paperworks can be required according to the assessment of [MEXT](http://www.mext.go.jp/) or equivalent organization.

Since you said you're from Vietnam —which is likely to be in 'southeastern asia' category, you'll need a 'proof of enrollment' and 'proof of financial support'. I think you should contact the embassy (+81-3-3452-7611/9 , Mon-Fri 09:00-18:00, lunch time 12:00-13:30) for exact requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked the visa section of Consulate General of the Republic of Korea in Osaka.
And here is what they said

```
Hello.

This is the visa section of Consulate General of the Republic of Korea in Osaka.

You can apply for a tourist visa if you are an exchange student at a university or a graduate school in Japan

If you are living in Osaka, Kyoto, Shiga, Nara and Wakayama, you can apply for a visa in here.

Below you will find the required documents for a visa application.

You have to apply for a visa in person and don’t need to make an appointment.

Please visit from 9 a.m to11 a.m (Mon~Fri).



1. A valid passport( It should be valid for more than six months before you would be allowed to apply for visa).

2. Residence card.

3. A completed Visa application.

4. A recent passport photo (3.5 x 4.5cm taken within 6months, color photo, white background).

5. Certificate of Student (It should be valid one month).

6. Return Flight E-Tickets or Return flight booking confirmation.

7. Hotel booking information (Address and contact number) or address and contact number in Korea where you will stay. 



￭ Visa processing requires 7 working days.

(Except of national holiday of Japan and 3/1, 8/15, 10/3, 10/9)

￭ Application time : 9:00~11:30(Monday~Friday)

￭ Pick up time : 14:00~16:00(Monday~Friday)

￭ we can not accept any documents which were issued more than 3 months before the date of your visa application has been accepted.

￭ We can require more documents when needed.



Regards,
```

I want to know what the below sentence means. Does anyone has an example?

```
we can not accept any documents which were issued more than 3 months before the date of your visa application has been accepted.
```

Comment: Your supporting documents must be 'recent' — it means your docs must have been issued within last 3 months.